# Fancyheader section doesn't call unnumbered section name after reference section

Tags: sectioning, fancyhdr

**Objective**
Create a header for an unnumbered section after the references.

1. I've succeeded in doing this by manually adding `{\titlefont\titleshape\nouppercase\markboth{\color{title}Supplemental}{\color{title}Supplemental}}` before `\opensupplement` in the dissertion.tex file, altough this creates an error *(Undefined control sequence.)*.
2. However, I'd prefer changing the .cls file, and the opensupplement function specifically. I tried using: `\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{\color{black}Supplemental}}` which only  works when the `\section` is numbered (so not with `\section*`, as I prefer to).

Code example:
Dissertation.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{dissertation}[2013/07/08 v1.0 TU Delft dissertation class]

\newif\if@nativefonts
\DeclareOption{nativefonts}{\@nativefontstrue}
\newif\if@print
\DeclareOption{print}{\@printtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[10pt]{book}

%% English is the default language, but Dutch is used for some sections.
\RequirePackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage{chapterbib}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage[sectionbib,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[noindentafter]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{titletoc}
\RequirePackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{bibentry}

%% Fancy style for the main matter.
\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[LE]{%
    {\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{%
      \raggedleft\thepage\hfill\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
    }%
  }
  \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE]{}
  \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

%% The mainmatter style is default for normal pages.
\pagestyle{mainmatter}

%% Print the current chapter and section at the top of the page in cyan.
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\color{black}#1}{}}
\renewcommand*\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ \color{black}#1}}

%% The setheader command can be used to print the title of unnumbered chapters
%% in the page header.
\newcommand*\setheader[1]{\markboth{\color{black}#1}{\color{black}#1}}

%% Change the headrule command (from fancyhdr.sty) to draw the line below the
%% header in the title color.
\renewcommand*\headrule{%
    \if@fancyplain%
        \let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth%
    \fi%
    {\color{black}\hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth}%
    \vskip-\headrulewidth%
}

%% Section titles start with the number in bold, followed by the name printed
%% in the title color.
\titleformat{\section}
    {\Large}
    {\bfseries\thesection.\ }
    {0pt}
    {\color{black}}

%% Create an unnumbered reference section.
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand*\bibname{\color{black}References}}
\newcommand*\references[1]{%
    \bibliographystyle{dissertation}%
    \bibliography{#1}%
}

\newcommand{\opensupplement}{
    \section*{Supplemental Material}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{S\arabic{table}}%
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure}}%
}
% restore the numbering system to arabic for the following chapter's sections
\newcommand{\closesupplement}{
    \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}
    \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
}
```

Dissertation.tex:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter[Some header]{Some header}
\label{chapter_4}
\newpage
\lipsum[1]\cite{knuth:1984}
\newpage
\references{dissertation}
\clearpage
\newpage
\opensupplement
\subsection*{Example}
\lipsum[2]
\closesupplement
\end{document}
```

I don't know why the supplemental section isn't added automatically. I guess it could be due to the `\reference` part, but searching for a way to stop that part other than `\clearpage` I have not found.

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem.

Kind regards,

Comment: The star variants `\section*`, `\subsection*` etc. of the standard classes do not change the running head, neither add an entry to the table of contents by intention. This is the same with or without `fancyhdr`. If you want *all* `\section` not to be numbered, just change counter `secnumdepth`. If you want just this `\section*` to have a running head add a suitable `\markright`. If you also want a ToC entry, you would also need an `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @cabohah Indeed secnumdepth has worked for me. Only thing is that all were added to the ToC. So where exactly should I add the `\markright`? In the .cls file after `\section*{Supplemental Material}` right? And thank you very much!